# Erro ao converter projeto Android para Maven

Tags: java, android, maven

Criei um projeto Android e logo após cliquei com o botão direito no projeto > Configure > Convert to Maven Project. Mas logo após fazer isso o aplicativo não inicia mais, ele apresenta o seguinte erro:

> Unable to instantiate activity ... with
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Alguém poderia me dar uma luz?

Comment: Tente o seguinte: Clique com o botão direito sobre a pasta do projeto → *Propriedades* → *Java Build Path* → *Order and Export* e marque a opção *Android Private Libraries*. Depois faça uma limpeza, *Projeto* → *Clean* e tente novamente.

Comment: A opção já está marcada @qmechanik.

Comment: @JoãoNeto, você está tentando resolver alguma necessidade específica ou fazendo algum tipo de estudo? Por que não utilizar o gestor de dependências "padrão" da plataforma Android, o Gradle?